# Proving each automorphism of a group $G$ fixes a normal subgroup of order $p^n$ if $p\nmid\frac{|G|}{p^n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have been going through Herstein's Algebra and came across this problem:

"$G$ has order $p^{n}m$ where $p$ is a prime, $p$ doesn't divide $m$. Suppose $G$ has a normal subgroup $P$ of order $p^n$. Prove that $f(P)=P$ for all automorphisms $f$ of $G$".

The question is within the section of Cauchy's theorem. I know that an automorphism is a mapping from $G$ to $G$. I also know that a normal subgroup follows $x^{-1}Px =P $ for all $x \in G$.

If you could provide me with a hint or two to solving the problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This is a consequence of the [Sylow theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N \leq G$ be a normal subgroup of order $p^n$, and let $\phi:G \rightarrow G$ be an automorphism.  Next, recall / prove that homomorphisms map subgroups to subgroups.  Since $\phi$ is an automorphism and thus bijective, $|N| = |\phi(N)| = p^n$.  In particular, both $N$ and $\phi(N)$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.

From here, apply the Sylow theorems.  What do they tell us about the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups if one of them is normal?  What can we conclude?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $PQ$ where $Q = f(P)$.